# Error: Tried to select attributes using Sequelize.cast or Sequelize.fn without specifying an alias for the result, during eager loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Data: an `Office` has many `OfficeLocations`, each of them has many `Ratings`. I need to write a query, that fetches only `Offices`, that have at lest one `Rating`. My query:

```
let condition = {
    include: [{
        model: OfficeLocation.unscoped(),
        attributes: [
            '"Office"."id" as "Office.id"',
            '"OfficeLocations"."id" AS "OfficeLocation.id"'
        ],
        include: [
            {
                model: Rating.unscoped(),
                attributes: [
                    '*',
                    sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('"OfficeLocations->Ratings"."id"'))
                ]
            }
        ],
        group: '"Office.id", "OfficeLocation.id"',
        having: sequelize.where(
            sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('"OfficeLocations->Ratings"."id"')),
            '>',
            0
        )
    }]
}

Office.findAll(condition).then(data => {
    res.send(data);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

But I have an error in console:

```
Error: Tried to select attributes using Sequelize.cast or Sequelize.fn without specifying an alias for the result, during eager loading. This means the attribute will not be added to the returned instance
at include.attributes.map.attr (/Users/.../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1307:17)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Object.generateInclude (/Users/.../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1287:52)
at Object.generateInclude (/Users/.../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1355:39)
```

I've also tried

```
where: sequelize.literal('COUNT(DISTINCT(`OfficeLocations`.`Ratings`.`id`)) > 0'),
```

instead of attributes/group/having, but it doesn't work too.

Thanks.

**Update**

This SQL query works as I need:

```
sequelize.query(`
    SELECT
    "Office"."id" as "Office.id",
    "Office"."name",
    "Office"."website",
    "OfficeLocations"."id" AS "OfficeLocations.id",
    COUNT("OfficeLocations->Ratings"."id") as "RatingsCount"

    FROM "Companies" AS "Office"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "OfficeLocations" AS "OfficeLocations"
        INNER JOIN "Ratings" AS "OfficeLocations->Ratings"
        ON "OfficeLocations"."id" = "OfficeLocations->Ratings"."OfficeLocationId"
    )
    ON "Office"."id" = "OfficeLocations"."OfficeId"

    GROUP BY "Office.id", "OfficeLocations.id"
    HAVING COUNT("OfficeLocations->Ratings"."id") > 0
`)
```

Except I want to fetch all data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, see [Model.findAll](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) syntax for `options` argument.

1. `group` and `having` are properties of `options` object.
2. For alias of selected columns/expr (`attributes` option) use array: `[expr, alias]`.
3. You can pass `attributes.include` and/or `attributes.exclude` arrays.
4. You can pass `include[].attributes` option for reference on attributes of the included Model.
5. Also you can use `include[].required` option for select between INNER AND OUTER JOIN.

Your case:

```
let options = {
        include: [
            {
                model: OfficeLocation,
                required: false, //false for OUTER JOIN, but I think that you can use INNER JOIN
                attributes: [
                    "id", //this is OfficeLocation.id, see 4th item above. 
                    [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col('`OfficeLocations->Ratings`.`id`')), "RatingsCount"]
                ],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: UserRating,
                        attributes: [],
                        required: true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        group: [
            `Office.id`,
            `OfficeLocations.id`
        ],
        having: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col('`OfficeLocations->Ratings`.`id`')), ">", 0)
    };
```

Note that aliases generated by Sequelize may changes, so you should update it for `Sequelize.col`.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! But I have a new issue - ` error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "`OfficeLocations->Ratings`"`. I made some mistake, that I have only nodel `Rating`, I renamed models of private project. S, it's `include: [{ model: Rating,...`

Comment: @zishe I don't know right way, I do something like this: turn off all options having string table names (attributes, group, having in your case), run query and see aliases for all tables generated by Sequelize and use it in options.

Comment: The point is - my sql generated query is the same as I working pure sql version, but it doesn't work! Probably I missing something.

Comment: You fixes are correct, I accepted the answer. Thank you for help!

Comment: @zishe Happy to help.